# Can't get .next() to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class so that the span text shows on hover, 
but only for that particular image not all images at once.

I can get it to add class to all the spans at once, but when I try to limit it to only the span being hovered nothing happens.  The problem seems to be when I add .next('span') - although I don't know why.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    $('.scroller-image').hover(function() {

         $(this).next('span').addClass('hover');
         }, function() {
         $(this).next('span').removeClass('hover');

    });
```

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="scroller-image">
    <span>image title</span>
    <img src="#" alt="#" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selects the next sibling - not child elements.  What you want is this
[children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$(this).children('span')// <-- this find direct children spans
```

or [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find('span')  //<-- this finds all descendent spans
```

Answer (score 3):

`.next()` finds siblings, not children. Try `$(this).children('span')`

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten your code a bit using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and by providing `this` as the context for the selector. Like this:

```
$('.scroller-image').hover(function(e) {
    $('span', this).toggleClass('hover', e.type === "mouseenter");
});
```

Comment: I'd do `.toggleClass( 'hover', e.type === 'mouseenter' )` just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for that. CSS can do this:

```
.scroller-image:hover span {
    /* the styles from your .hover class */
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VbZ2G/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add the "hover" class to the span that is a child of the div that is being hovered?  I think `.next()` goes to the sibling, why not try

```
.children('span')
```